# Excel Pivotchart not showing end of data labels

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pivot chart which draws a line chart for a particular set of data, which can range from 2000-6000 values, all timestamped. For example:

```
01/04/2019 07:00    1.658478141
01/04/2019 07:14    1.713099122
01/04/2019 07:30    1.76636517
01/04/2019 07:44    1.815220237
01/04/2019 07:59    1.865214229
01/04/2019 08:15    1.915204883
01/04/2019 08:30    1.986165404
```

Where 01/04/2019 08:30 is the last value.

The actual line changes to represent all of the points within my table, however the x axis label never accurately shows the last data item. I do not mind what is shown inbetween the start and end, but it is imperative that the end time on the chart label reflects the end time of the data.

For example, for the above data, this is what the chart shows:

[image: Chart 1]

So far I have tried various methods found, such as changing the axis type to "text" as opposed to automatic, and this didn't work. I also tried to have a chart that referenced a "named" range, but this didn't work either.

If I resize the chart then the labels change, but it wouldn't be possible to have a chart wide enough for all 6000 labels to fit in the screen.

[image: Example of expanded chart]

It seems like this should be easily achieved, but I can't figure out any other configurations to try.

Comment: Please add more detail, ideally including descriptions (add screenshots) of what's happening vs what's expected, and tell us what you've tried and how it hasn't worked so far.

Comment: @AlexM I have amended the post now and added more detail.

Comment: I updated the post to include the images; hopefully it catches somebody's eye. It's harder to get good help when the question can't really be answered when initially asked.